# How does sitecore search (Lucene) handle duplicate field names stored in index?

Tags: content-search, lucene

Luke is showing two fields with the same name for a document. When executing a search does sitecore search both fields or does it only search the first one. And if that's the case is there a way to either specify which one to prioritize or to overwrite with the latest one?

The case below is from indexing a PDF "specialMediaItem" is the item's name.

[image: Lucene Duplicate field name Image]

Edit: I found a reference to: [Appending index fields in Lucene](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3927/appending-index-fields-in-lucene) However, Luke makes it appear as if it were two seperate fields instead of appending them together.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90041/discussion-on-question-by-adam-hess-how-does-sitecore-search-lucene-handle-dup).